# Prove that the set of all $\mathbb{R}$-module homomorphisms under a certain operation is an abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The question is given in the following picture:

[image]

**My answer is as follows:**

Let $f,g,h \in Hom_{R}(A,B)$

1- The closure is proved in the problem statement.

2-$(f+g)(a) = f(a) + g(a) = g(a) + f(a) = (g+f)(a).$

3-The identity element is the zero map as mentioned in the problem statement,
$(0+f)(a) = 0(a) + f(a) = 0 + f(a) = f(a),$ and $(f+0)(a) = f(a) + 0(a) = f(a) + 0 = f(a).$

4-$\forall f$,$\exists$(-f) such that $((-f)+f)(a)=(-f)(a)+f(a)=0,$ and $(f + (-f))(a) = f(a) + (-f)(a) = 0$

5-$((f + g) + h)(a) = ((f + g)(a)) + h(a) = (f(a)+g(a)) + h(a) = f(a) + (g(a) + h(a)) = f(a) + (g + h)(a).$

I do not know how to prove that $(-f)$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, could anyone help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: Given $f,g: A \longrightarrow B, R$-module homomorphisms, you need to show that $f+g: A \longrightarrow B$ and $(-f): A\longrightarrow B$ are $R$-module homomorphisms.

Comment: You should also *define* $-f$. Or else how can you justify its existence?

Comment: You have not shown that $(f+g)(a_1 + a_2) = (f+g)(a_1) + (f+g)(a_2)$, nor that $(f+g)(ra) =r((f+g)(a))$, all that is given in the problem statement is that $f+g$ is a *map* $A \to B$.

Comment: In the given statement, as far as I can see, it is only given $(f+g)(a):=f(a)+g(a), a \in A$. There is never a word, again as far as I can see, that with this definition $f+g$ is an $R$-module homomorphism. That's what precisely I mean.

Comment: How can I do this ? could you clarify @Krish

Comment: @Krish  yeah I realized that I was wrong.

Comment: See @DavidWheeler 's comment. That's what you need to show.

Comment: yeah I realized that I am wrong @DavidWheeler  thank you :)

Comment: I do not know how to prove that $(-f)$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, could you help me please?@Krish

Comment: I do not know how to prove that $(-f)$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, could you help me please?@DavidWheeler